# When to write JSX return in parents and when to write it in child in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am finding some videos where render jsx code (HTML rendering on page) written in parent component and sometime its written in child component !

both are working fine on html page , hence want to understand whats happening !can somebody please explain it ?

please see example code

```
ParentComponent

import React , {Component} from 'react';
import Ischild from './ischild';


class Otherparent extends Component {    

    state = {

        title :'Click Me',
        age : 30,
        name : 'Trupti Thakkar'
    }

   
    myNewFun = () => {
       
        this.setState ( {age:this.state.age-10} )
    }
    callFromHere = (newTitle) => {

        this.setState ({title:newTitle});
    }
   

    render() {    
        return (     
            <React.Fragment>
            <span>This is span in parent</span>
            <button onClick={this.myNewFun}></button>
            <Ischild age = {this.state.age} doWhatever={this.callFromHere.bind (this, 'I am clicked','Its Jeny Now')} title= {this.state.title} name= {this.state.name}/>    
            </React.Fragment>
        );  
    }
}
export default Otherparent;

** Child Component **

import React  from 'react';


const Ischild = (props) => {    
    return ( 
        <React.Fragment>
            <span> {props.title}</span>
                             <span>This is span in children</span>

                 </React.Fragment>
           
            ); 
};


export default Ischild;
```

I can see both span executed on html browser also i can see both buttons including child and parents component are there on html browser !

Ive seen videos but unable to understand where to defined what ? Can somebody please explain ?

Thank you so very much !

Answer (score 1):

Your parent component `OtherParent` is simply just rendering the `IsChild` component, and your `IsChild` component is simply rendering whatever JSX you are returning from it. This is exactly what react is based upon, composable components, where parents render their children.

To answer your question about what renders where, that is totally up to you and how your app should be structured, but essentially components should only really care about themselves and pass data or callbacks/functions to their children as props

Comment: Noted ! My query is if i write span in parents with some content and also one span in child with some other content , both i can see display on browser ! just wanted to know where to write it and what is correct way !

Comment: Also, if i can get same thing with this.state.name on parent page, why to get it in child and execute it with props.name ?

Comment: You can think of state as a data store within a component, but it's only available to that component, not its parent or it's children. If you need to pass data to a child, you pass it to the child via props, whereby in the child you can access it by `this.props.<prop_name>`

Comment: Thanks ! what i am not getting here is why i need to use child component and send data there whereas i can just display data here and make function on click button as well ! is there anything related to state im missing out here ?

Comment: You don't have to. What you will find in react is that you could put everything into one big component, and it will still work. A well architected react app will have small components so that each component can be easily tested, has clear inputs and outputs, and can improve performance as react can render only what it needs to when data / state changes. You lose all of those benefits when you keep everything in big components